# CRITICAL issue with iOS, CocoonJS and Facebook

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, permissions, cocoonjs

I've just published in the Apple's Appstore a **CocoonJS** powered **Javascript** game that integrates some **Facebook** functions. After creating my app to Facebook, I spent weeks testing it in the CocoonJS Launcher, and I found the following:

- In **iOS**, the user should **grant permissions** to apps that tries to access Facebook through the phone's **Settings -> Facebook**, where a list of apps appear.

I did so with the CocoonJS Launcher and then Facebook started working as expected. However, the final app (generated through the Cloud Compiler) has just been published in the store and, after trying to access Facebook from within the app, the app says that the user should grant permission from Facebook's settings (as I did with the Launcher), but **it doesn't appear at the phone's Settings -> Facebook** (that is, the list of apps that use Facebook and where it appeared the Launcher).

I've created my app in Facebook, retrieved its ID number, put it in the CocoonJS Cloud Compiler (both for Apple and Android) and, of course, called the "init" function inside the game with the corresponding Facebook app code... Even though it worked with the Launcher, it doesn't work with the app, and now my app is alive and no Facebook integration can be done (which is a real mess, because almost every game function uses it now)...

How could I solve it? What can be happening? Might it have something to do with the Cloud Compiler, or maybe it's related to the JS code?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As states in help center, do some testing first with a custom launcher:
http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/200767268-Custom-Launcher

The CocoonJS launcher you download from the store has the configuration string of Ludei:
http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/200924496-Social

The problem may not have been in the submission, but in the development of the application.

In case you feel it's a bug, please fill a bug report with the following template in their help center.

The template guide:
http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/203459717-How-to-report-a-CocoonJS-bug

The forum to post the issue (troubleshooting section):
http://support.ludei.com/hc/communities/public/topics/200011348-Problems-Troubleshooting